# Iterate through log file line by line looking for IP address pattern with RegEx. Each IP will need to use the extend method to add each ip to list IPS

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a script and trying to iterate through a log file line by line using regex to look for IP address pattern and then use the extend method to add each ip to the list ips. I believe that I have got everything right up until the point of iteration and then trying to print(ips), as you can see in the script.

```
    import urllib.request
    import json
    import datetime
    import os
    import re 
    import azuremaps
```

3 empty lists I have created to store data found

```
     ips = []
     unique_ips = []
     toJson = []
```

Log file I have opened
file = open('logs/access.log', 'r')

This might be where I have messed up trying to use regex to iterate through the log file line by line to get ip addresses and then using the extend method to store those in list ips. Would like this code to be less than 5 lines.

```
    pattern = re.compiler(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \.\d{1,3})')
    for line in file:
    ips.extend(pattern.search(line)[0])
    print(ips)
```

New list populated removing all duplicates.

```
    unique_ips = list(set(ips))
```

Before I move forward I need to validate my lists, however when I type print(ips) in the terminal I get bash:syntax error near unexpected token 'ips'

```
    #print(ips)
    #print(len(ips))
    #print(len(unique_ips))
    #print(unique_ips)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to do it line-by-line?

Assuming the access.log file as:

```
43.53.250.2
65.66.66.69
noise234.85.98.12something
whatever65.66.66.69
```

I think you can try this:

```
import re

with open('logs/access.log', 'r') as file:
    file = file.read()

pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
ips = pattern.findall(file)
unique_ips = list(set(ips))

print(unique_ips)
```

```
['234.85.98.12', '65.66.66.69', '43.53.250.2']
```

Notes regarding your code:

- I believe it should be re.compile instead of re.compiler
- It looks like there's an extra space in your regex string
- I think you can just use `append` since you're trying to `extend` your list with one element at a time anyway.